# Accessing Google Reader subscriptions with OAuth2 access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, google-reader

Is that possible to access Google Reader subscriptions using OAuth2 access_token? I've created Google APIs project, setting up domain and created javascript code that receives OAuth2 token. It works well for other Google APIs, but not for Google Reader OPML subscriptions. Could anyone hint me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12724154/1244210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems I've solved myself. The trick was that after obtaining "code" token from browser, you should perform call to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token to obtain access_token, token_type, expires_in and refresh_token.

Another important thing is that you should define scope as http://www.google.com/reader/api not http://www.google.com/reader/api/* as stated somewhere.

Comment: Hello,

I am trying to use the Google Oauth 2.0 playground to access the Google Reader APIs. I am using the http://www.google.com/reader/api/ scope, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would highly appreciated. 

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724154/how-to-access-google-feedsreader-with-oauth2-0