# How to access Google feeds(Reader) with OAuth2.0?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, google-feed-api

I want to access google feeds with OAuth2.0. I used [google-oauth-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/) to get my access token. How can I use it to access the feeds API?

I referenced [dailymotion-cmdline-sample](http://samples.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/dailymotion-cmdline-sample/instructions.html), and changed SCOPE as `http://www.google.com/reader/api` to fetch the credential.

It returns:

```
401 Unauthorized

You must be signed in to access this stream.
```

And I don't know what's wrong...

I also read some posts which shows OAuth2.0 is possible to do this job, but they are not detailed enough to me:

[Read access only for the Google OAuth 2.0 token?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fougrapi/U_8eT4yyLsY)

[Using the Google Reader API](http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/)

[Accessing Google Reader subscriptions with OAuth2 access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530790/accessing-google-reader-subscriptions-with-oauth2-access-token)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with the scope as `http://www.google.com/reader/api/*`.
I solved it by changing the scope to `http://www.google.com/reader/api/`.
Try with the `/` at the end.